# Django & node.js : throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: django, node.js, socket.io

I am giving a try to the Django socket.io and node.js example by [Realtime Django](https://github.com/mburst/django-realtime-tutorial.git)

when I am trying to send the message from a browser I am getting the error from node server that is

```
events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)
```

Since I started with node.js and socket.io I am not able to figure out this error.

Please tell me what might I am doing wrong.

Also some suggest some working example of django, node.js and socket.io if possible.

Comment: Because you're not listening to an "error" event, its unhandled and your app crashes. You need to add the listener and log the message.

Comment: Do you have server codes sample?

Comment: I dont have rigth now

Comment: Here is the code tyou have to clone it only https://github.com/mburst/django-realtime-tutorial.git

Comment: Please tell me what i am doing wrong I just copied this code for test

Comment: I think you don't have permission to ports below 1024, try high numbered port like 8080

Comment: Are you running your Django server on port 3000? The Node server depends on that: [see this line](https://github.com/mburst/django-realtime-tutorial/blob/master/nodejs/chat.js#L41)

Answer (score 1):

the example uses redis as database backend, and the node redis-client. do you have installed the redis database? it looks like this is the problem.

if you have, the redis-client module provides an optional option param where you can define host, port etc... in your createClient (if you dont have installed redis the standard way):

```
var sub = redis.createClient(...maybe put an options object here...);
```