# Django pet_person.user_id may not be NULL

Tags: django

Im working on an app where pet users can create profile and upload pictures of their pets.

I got this error when I access the profile page which I can't seem to understand. I created an app similar to this recently but ever seen I associated my models to User. I got errors tumbling down. I appreciate all the help from everyone and I thank you all.

I'm trying to let users upload a picture of themself at the profile page.

```
 pet_person.user_id may not be NULL

 Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
 C:\o\mysite\pet\views.py in Profile 
        form.save()
```

I think this error is relating to my models and my Profile function at views.py

My models.py

```
  from django.db import models
  from django.db.models.signals import post_save
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Pet(models.Model):
    Person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

Parts of my views.py

```
def Profile(request):
    form = PictureForm(request.POST ,request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render_to_response('profile.html',{'form':PictureForm()},context_instance = RequestContext(request)
)
```

My forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from django.forms import ModelForm
 from pet.models import *

 class UserRegistration(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label =(u'Verify Password'), widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user',)
        fields = ('username','email','name','password','password1')

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError("That user is already taken , please select another ")

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password1']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")
        return self.cleaned_data

 class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    model = Person
    fields = ('username','password')


 class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('image',)
```

@master!

```
def Profile(request):
    form = PictureForm(request.POST ,request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        event = form.save(commit=False)
        event.user=request.user
    event.save()
    return render_to_response('profile.html',{'form':PictureForm()},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Can I post my answer or it is already fix?

Comment: @catherine Yes please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('image',)

def Profile(request):
    person = Person(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PictureForm(request.POST ,request.FILES or None, instance=person)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 
    return render_to_response('profile.html',{'form':PictureForm()},context_instance = RequestContext(request)
```

Comment: Cathi  I given you the link please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640741/django-node-js-throw-arguments1-unhandled-error-event

Comment: I am getting the problem in that question  you have to check

Comment: I am trying from two days did n't get any thing

Comment: @catherine what should i do :( . I want to create accounts so pet users can create their own profile

Comment: @donkeyboy72 you get that error because you set your user field to OneToOneField. In OneToOneField, you can only save one unique id so you must change it to ForeignKey instead.

Comment: Have you delete your database and sync again because you change it to ForeignKey?

Comment: Didn't solve your problem? You want me to check all the apps?

Comment: @catherine Thank you for spending time helping me today . I need to go sleep and i'll to figure out this error tomorrow . Thank you buddy!

Comment: Ok, I will take a look maybe later or tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

In Below model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
```

you have a Field called `user`   That is not mentioned anywhere in your forms.

And according to Your model `Person`  field cannot be null .

TO overcome that problem

save your form like

```
`obj =  form.save(`commit = False`)`
 obj.user =Person(user=request.user) # If user is logged in 
 obj.save()
```

Comment: your english is fine. The Pet model has nothing to do with this yet . I'm trying to save the image into Person module but I cannot save the form because Person cannot be null.

Comment: but in your form you are passing only image field then how can you expect for the user Person detail

Comment: Does Person is logged in  ?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is when a user signs up , He only signs up with user and name . Once he is login and redirected into profile . He can upload a picture which can be added to Person Model .

Comment: Do you reckon the image should be in a seperate model?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813189/django-userprofile-with-unique-foreign-key-in-django-admin

Comment: Yeah , I have no idea why it's not working  . I'm gonna read your link

Comment: nope column user_id is not unique but I thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that in `PictureForm` you are only asking for the image field.  However, this form is actually for a `Person` model.  Your `Person` requires a user and a name as well as an image (in fact, the image is the only optional part).  Seeing as these are not coming from your form you need to supply these yourself.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form

Comment: I understand I can't just update the image alone. It need to be with user and image